# Devemos ter o motivo de fechamento de pergunta "Não Construtivo"?

Tags: novo-recurso, status-intencional

O StackOverflow em inglês possui o motivo de fechamento "Não Construtivo":

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que acham de trazê-lo para cá?

Perguntas não-construtivas aqui costumam ser fechadas como "fora de escopo". Vejam [este exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32653/7261). Acontece que "fora de escopo" existe para perguntas não-relacionadas com programação, que não é o caso da pergunta acima (entre outras).

Comment: _"O StackOverflow em inglês **possuia** o motivo de fechamento "Não Construtivo""_

Comment: Infelizmente tem uma quantidade considerável de usuários que não sabe a diferença entre votar como ampla e fora de escopo, e além disso vota pra fechar quando não entende do assunto. Imagine se tiverem que julgar o que é ou não construtivo...

Comment: Acho que o Stack Overflow original deixou de ter esse motivo de fechamento porque não era muito construtivo (*drumroll*).

Answer (score 3):

Os motivos para fechamento aqui e no StackOverflow em Inglês costumam seguir o mesmo padrão de uma forma macro, e sempre que ocorre uma mudança lá ela é refletida aqui. O motivo de fechamento em questão já não está mais vigente lá faz um certo tempo. Como você pode ver na imagem da pergunta em questão, a pergunta foi fechada em 2011, de lá para cá muitas coisas mudaram no site.

O assunto em questão foi tratado do Meta StackOverflow, nesse tópico:  [Closing changes: on hold, unclear, too broad, opinion-based, off-topic reasons, bye-bye to Too Localized](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184154/229289)

Uma transcrição em tradução livre apenas dos trechos que tratam do assunto de motivo de fechamento "Não construtivo" são os seguintes:

- O tom do motivo de fechamento gerava mais discussão do que melhorias; e
- Não deixava claro o que o AP precisava melhorar na pergunta dele.

Os motivos de fechamento "Não é uma questão de verdade" e "Não construtivo" foram substituídas por:

- Não é claro o que você está perguntando;
- Muito amplo; e
- Principalmente baseada em opiniões.

Consequentemente, se você quiser mesmo lutar por essa causa é necessário que você tenha bons argumentos e principalmente vários cases demonstrando que os motivos de fechamento atuais são inadequados, e principalmente lutar contra todos os pontos que já foram colocados de forma concisa no tópico que eu linkei acima, caso contrário você terá  pouquíssimas chances de obter sucesso na jornada.

> O que acham de trazê-lo para cá?

Eu acho que não convém.

Comment: Eu tenho a péssima mania de não procurar as coisas no http://meta.stackexchange.com/ Realmente faz bem mais sentido do jeito que está.

Comment: Até fecharia a pergunta para não poluir o espaço do Meta, mas por conta dessa resposta não posso.

Comment: Relaxa, é uma parte do material em inglês que agora está disponível para o público lusófono. Se você teve essa dúvida outros poderão tê-la também.

Comment: O @Andrey achou que esta não era uma pergunta construtiva :P